# Django: Setting LOGGER doesn't work

Tags: python, django, debugging, logging, console

I'm having trouble with Django's logging system. My goal is to log all types of logs to the files, and only log to the console if `DEBUG` is set to `True` (which it is right now)

As it is, the log files remain blank (although they are created by Django). When I start the server (using `python3 manage.py runserver`) I see the following in the shell:

```
Warning!
Error!

... (normal server stuff)
```

But nothing is written to any of the log files.

And if I un-comment `logging.error('== == START LOGGER == ==')` and `logr.setLevel('DEBUG')` in **__init__.py**, then the shell reads:

```
ERROR:root:== == START LOGGER == ==
DEBUG:project:Debug!
INFO:project:Info!
WARNING:project:Warning!
ERROR:project:Error!

... (normal server stuff)
```

And **django.log** displays:

```
DEBUG (0.000) SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0; args=None
DEBUG (0.000) SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0; args=None
DEBUG (0.001) SHOW FULL TABLES; args=None
DEBUG (0.000) SELECT `django_migrations`.`app`, `django_migrations`.`name` FROM `django_migrations`; args=()
```

But all other logs remain blank.

### Here is my project app

**__init__.py**

```
import logging

#logging.error('== == START LOGGER == ==')
logr = logging.getLogger('project')
#logr.setLevel('DEBUG')

logr.debug('Debug!')
logr.info('Info!')
logr.warning('Warning!')
logr.error('Error!')
```

### Here are my LOGGING settings

**settings.py**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
        'simpler': {
            'format': '%(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default':{
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/err.log',
            'maxBytes': 5242880, # 5MB file size
            'encoding': 'utf-8',
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
        'debug':{
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/debug.log',
            'maxBytes': 5242880, # 5MB file size
            'encoding': 'utf-8',
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
        'django':{
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/django.log',
            'maxBytes': 5242880, # 5MB file size
            'encoding': 'utf-8',
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
        'mail':{
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/mail.log',
            'maxBytes': 5242880, # 5MB file size
            'encoding': 'utf-8',
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simpler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['django'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['django'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'project': {
            'handlers': ['default', 'debug', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

Why does it show `DEBUG` and `INFO` when I write `logging.error('== == START LOGGER == ==')` and `logr.setLevel('DEBUG')` ?? Why don't the log files get written to? I've searched through similar questions and their answers for hours with no success. Thanks.

Edit: Things I've tried:

Changing `'disable_existing_loggers'` to `False`

Changing `'level': 'DEBUG',` to `'level': 'NOTSET',` and `'level': 'ERROR',`

Removing all but necessary settings

Changing `'propagate'` to `True`

Removing `'console'` from `'handlers'` (which does absolutely nothing)

Comment: Aside from a few Django-specific items, the only entry in `settings.LOGGING['loggers']` is `project`.  Is any of your code in a module other than `project`?

Comment: no, right now its a very basic django app with only one module (called "project")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **__init__.py** file is called before **settings.py**

Move your code from **__init__.py** to any other file, which will be called after **settings.py**

Comment: This is exactly right. Thank you very much! I just moved all code from **__init__.py** to a new **main.py** in the same folder (with a function called `start`), calling it in **urls.py** by: from .main import start
     start()`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough points to add a comment, so I'll mention in here that if your logging format uses `%(name)s` then a useful extension to the above answer is, in the files where you have:

```
logr = logging.getLogger('project')
```

you could use:

```
logr = logging.getLogger('project.%s' % __name__)
```

This would then mean your project logger reports the full App name, eg. *'project.polls.views'*